# Azure AD B2C - Password Reset custom page layout HTML after emailed code

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I've personalized a user flow to use a HTML page and it works very well. I've also added it to the login user flow.

My problem is when the user goes to the reset password flow (that is right), send the code to his email and click "Continue". The page after, where the user inputs the new password, doesn't have the HTML that I've personalized and I don't find where I can do set it.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

So, I've found it!

On `Page Layout` there are multiple Layouts associated with the User Flow.
I just added the custom page to the Layout `Change password page` and that's it.